# make chartjs legend labels tabbable

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to make the labels on a chart tabbable.
In this implementation, I'm using [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2).
However, the configuration options object remains standard to chartjs.

Example code:

```js
    const options = {
        legend: {
            onHover: (e) => {
                console.log(e.target); // this is the entire legend, not individual labels
            },
            labels: {
                onHover: (e) => { 
                /* doesn't work; trying to see if have access to e.target even to do DOM manipulation... */
                    console.log(e.target); // doesn't fire
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, clicking on these labels filters the display of that dataset, I just need a way to make then tabbable with the enter key as well as being clickable.

I have searched the chartjs documentation, but cannot find a way to add hover and focus events, or enable focus-ability of the labels (Fall 2014 to Fall 2018 in screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think by specifying just position you will get result.

```
options: {
    legend: {
        position: 'top'
    },
}
```

Comment: I think by specifying just position you will get result.

Comment: I editted your answer because it was flagged as low quality. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering more questions.

Comment: Thanks, but this only adjusts the position of the legend. The labels are still not selectable (do not receive focus) using the tab key.